# Proving that $-\ln(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})$

Tags: solution-verification, logarithms

Show $-\ln(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})=ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})$

Can somebody verify that my solution is correct (or incorrect!) and also show me alternative methods to do this? Thanks!

Let $r=-\ln(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})$ and $s=ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})$

$\rightarrow e^r=(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})^{-1}$ and $e^s = x+\sqrt{x^2-1}$

$\rightarrow \frac{e^s}{e^r} = (x+\sqrt{x^2-1})(x-\sqrt{x^2-1}) = x^2 - (x^2 - 1) = 1$

Thus $e^r=e^s$ and so $r=s$

Comment: This looks good to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof looks fine to me. You can also do this: $\ln(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})+\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})=\ln\left((x-\sqrt{x^2-1})(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})\right)=\ln 1 =0$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Your solution looks fine.

You can also try to apply the identity $\alpha\ln|a| = \ln|a|^{\alpha}$, then multiply and divide by the conjugate of the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good.

But note that it's really just a matter of observing that $x \pm \sqrt{x^2-1}$ are reciprocals, since
$$\frac{1}{x + \sqrt{x^2-1}} = \frac{1}{x + \sqrt{x^2-1}}\cdot\frac{x - \sqrt{x^2-1}}{x - \sqrt{x^2-1}}$$
$$=\frac{x - \sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^2-(x^2-1)}$$
$$= \frac{x - \sqrt{x^2-1}}{1}$$
$$=x - \sqrt{x^2-1}$$

This means that their logarithms are opposites, since $\log u^{-1} = -\log u$.